# Mac and iOS in-app purchasing behaving differently

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase

On iOS, After initiating a payment the defaultQueue contains a single "dummy" transaction that contains no transactionId. After the transaction is finished (completed or failed) the "dummy" transaction is replaced with a new transaction which contains an actual transactionId.

However, the Mac version is behaving differently. After initiating the payment, I am seeing updatedTransactions called twice and the defaultQueue contains two "dummy" transactions with no transactionId. After the transaction is finished (completed or failed) a third transaction is added to the queue which contains an actual transactionId. When finishTransaction is called on this transaction the first time, it typically removes one of the dummy transactions from the queue. A looper that we have running finds the finished transaction still in the queue and handles it. The second call to finishTransaction removes it from the queue. At this point the defaultQueue still contains one instance of the "dummy" transaction which never resolves and stays in the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state indefinitely.

This behavior not only results in a memory leak, as the queue continues to grow after each purchase, it also results in our in-game purchase handlers getting called twice.

I have only tested this in a sandbox environment.

Has anyone encountered similar issues on Mac?

Comment: Update: I ended up implementing a work around for this issue, but the problem does still exist for me.